# Ajax Popupextender to Display a UserControl?

Tags: asp.net

I am currently working in a project where I want to show a Feedback kind of form to user.The Feedback form is made into a user Control.Now How Do i set this usercontrol to show with PopupExtender.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JQuery and JQueryUI to show form in dialog.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/